# Pass lastinsertedid from mysql to aspx file

Tags: c#, mysql

This is my webapi file,here in variable 'imageId' I can get my lastinserted id,so i want to pass this id to an aspx file in the same project,is it possible?

```
        string connString = "Server=localhost;database=abcd;uid=abcd;password=abcd";
        try
         {
          using (MySqlConnection mcon  = new MySqlConnection(connString))
            {
              using (MySqlCommand cmd = mcon.CreateCommand())
               {
                 mcon.Open();
                 cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO `contentupload`.`content_document`
                   (
                   `content`)
                   VALUES (@content);";
                   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@content", content);
                   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                   long imageId = cmd.LastInsertedId;
                   mcon.Close();
                   return;
                   }
                  }
                 }

        catch (MySqlException e)
        {
            return ;
        }

    }
```

Comment: yes its possible bro, eg you got the id  in some var like var id = you last inserted id, next is Response.Redirect("Page.aspx?id"+id);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will work for you..!! and you dont need to close the connection explicitly, it will be closed as soon it leave the scope..

```
   string connString = "Server=localhost;database=abcd;uid=abcd;password=abcd";
    try
     {
      using (MySqlConnection mcon  = new MySqlConnection(connString))
        {
          using (MySqlCommand cmd = mcon.CreateCommand())
           {
             mcon.Open();
             cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO `contentupload`.`content_document`
               (
               `content`)
               VALUES (@content);";
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@content", content);
               cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
               long imageId = cmd.LastInsertedId;
               Response.Redirect("YourPage.aspx?imageID="+imageId.ToString());
               }
              }
             }

    catch (MySqlException e)
    {
        return ;
    }

}
```

and on YourPage.aspx Load event simply retrieve it

```
var imageId = Request.QueryString["imageId"];
```

and convert it and use it properly..
hope it helps.